# Schedule a job - Mongodb - Run a view every day

Tags: mongodb-4.0

how is MongoDB not able to schedule queries?

I would like to know if it's possible to run a single insert every day:

```
use Database

var documents = db.Viewname.find({"modifiedOn":{"$gte": new Date(ISODate().getTime() -1000*86400*1)}})
use Second_Database_to_insert
documents.forEach(function(x){db.Collection_inserted.insert(x)})
```

is there a way to run a script connecting on mongo? I don't want to use more 3rd party tools because this database (not the database itself, but the support we have) is already very expensive.

With sql server we can easily create a job and schedule it to run every day.

Mongo 4.0 on windows ( actually I'm running noSQLBooster on my windows. mongo itself is on the cloud on a linux machine. we dont have access directly to this linux machine, only via nosqlbooster. and we have ATLAS)

Comment: MongoDB isn't the most used database in the world. It is not even in the top 5.

Comment: Oh i think I'vechosen the wrong words haha.